# Tesseract 3.05 mistakes 0 and 8 C++ VS 2015

Tags: c++, oop, opencv

I am using OpenCV to process and crop an image, and then pass it to tesseract, but the zero digit is mistaken as eight (probably due to the inclined line in the zero).
Here is the cropped image: https://image.ibb.co/bM7Lq6/zCroped.jpg

And the result:

> Too few characters. Skipping this page
> OSD: Weak margin (0.00) for 3 blob text block, but using orientation anyway: 0
>
> Result 1: [9.80]

I have tried on other image and the result is OK, but in the cropped image the inclined line in the zero is weaker.
https://image.ibb.co/bsD73R/zCroped.jpg

I am not very good at image processing.
Could you please give me an idea how to remove this inclined line? Or is there another way to help tesseract?

Update:

Actually, for this particular image, after performing `GaussianBlur`

```
>GaussianBlur(thresh, imFixThresh, Size(3, 3), 2, 2);
>adaptiveThreshold(imFixThresh, imFixThresh, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 15, 25);
```

the result was OK.

In the resulting image, you could see the inclined line is partly removed.
https://image.ibb.co/fAQJcm/test1.jpg

Comment: If you are working with the same font type for your application, you can consider training your tesseract with the specific font. However, if you can decide on the font, try to change to a better font type.

Comment: No, the fonts cannot be predefined. Thank you for the fast reply!